# How to debug Node.js with Firefox?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox

I'm aware of how to access the Chrome Dev Tools with Google Chrome to debug Node.js applications: just go to about://inspect.

I encountered a line of text on MDN mentioning that Firefox could be used for Node.js applications, but going to about://inspect in Firefox doesn't work. I'd like to know how this would be done in Firefox, if it is indeed possible.

Comment: It's a fairly complicated process for Firefox. I'd recommend [**their own guide**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_with_WebIDE) on connecting remote devices.

Answer (score 15):

Because Firefox uses a different Javascript engine (Gecko) than Node.js (V8), it's impossible to use the Firefox dev tools to debug Node scripts. As of this post, MDN says as much in their "Remote Debugging" article:

> You can connect the developer tools to Gecko-based runtimes...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called `node-firefox` that you can use for that, you can download it from:

```
npm install node-firefox
```

Here's the source code: https://github.com/mozilla/node-firefox

And a introductory guide: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/02/introducing-node-firefox/

Comment: actually this concerns front-end debugging, not server-side debugging as chrome does